# Why doesn't Google 2 Factor Auth ask for a code?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, google

I set up Google 2 Factor auth to use 2 Factor Auth with certain sites. But reading over the help suggests that Google 2 Factor Auth is only used to log into Google services like Gmail.

But when I log into Gmail, to does not ask for 2 Factor Auth code.

Is Google 2 Factor Auth used to log into Google services?

Where is the documentation for using Google 2 Factor Auth to log into non-Google services?

Comment: Because you haven't enabled it yet. Go here and enable it https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig?hl=en

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for help to use a web service.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. If you need help setting up Google 2FA, you may ask on [webapps.se], but please clarify what you're having trouble with.

Comment: I'm asking for help in understanding the Google 2FA process. Rod answered the question very clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google calls it 2 step verification. 
They do not ask for it every time you log in. Only when you log in from a new computer, if you have not used the code in a while, if they think there is something suspicious with your account usage, or, if you clear your cookies from your browser so it appears to be a login from a new PC.

They use this system so that it is not such a big pain in the neck for newbies to 2 factor auth. This is to help convince people to add the 2nd factor.

The theory is that many users are hesitant to use 2-factor because it is an extra step they need to take. If they only need to do it once in a while, but it ensures that someone in China trying to hack the account has that extra hoop to jump through, they are more likely to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it works on Google. Most likely what happened, IMHO, is it didn't ask because you were on the same computer that you set it up with.

I see you've asked [another question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39720/do-google-2-factor-auth-backup-codes-work-for-logging-into-google-or-other-sites) about non-Google services, so I won't answer that here.